# Trailing data pushing job in Queue

Tags: laravel, queue, php-carbon

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and i'm trying to push a job later in Queue but carbon is returning an Trailing data error...

I've first tried to change the DateTime i was givig to function for a Carbon. Didn't solved the problem.

```php
Queue::later($datetime1, 'QueueHelper@ActionArret', array('ordre' => $ordre,'cible' => $cible, 'action' => 'ARRET'), 'ARRET');
```

Where $datetime1 is set like this : $datetime1 = new DateTime($dateD);
i've tried to debug $datetime1 the object is a correct DateTime object...
Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, in the $dtaa argument i was giving $order as an object and since i give the id of the object it works...
like this

```php
Queue::later($datetime1, 'QueueHelper@ActionArret', array('ordre' => $ordre->id,'cible' => $cible, 'action' => 'ARRET'), 'ARRET');
```